# FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, progressdialog, android-support-library

I'm using Android Support Library (v4) and ActionBarSherlock. I'm trying to close a progress dialog programatically. I've coded a small utility class to help with dialog management.

The dialog is shown from an `AsyncTask.onPreExecute`. It gets displayed correctly. Then I fire a config change by rotating the device, which destroys the activity (onDestroy calls `AsyncTask.cancel(true)`). `AsyncTask.onCancelled` is called, and is in this method where I'm trying to close the dialog. But nothing happens. Here are the helper functions to show and close the dialog:

```
    public abstract class DialogHelperActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

        protected void showProgressDialog(final String msg, final String tag){      
            FragmentTransaction ft = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            DialogFragment dialogFragment = ProgressDialogFragment.newInstance(msg);

            ft.add(dialogFragment, tag);
            ft.disallowAddToBackStack();
            ft.commitAllowingStateLoss(); //If I try with regular commit(), exceptions are thrown.
        }

        protected void closeDialog(final String tag){
            FragmentManager fm = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
            Fragment dialogFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(tag);        

            if(dialogFragment != null){
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.remove(dialogFragment);
                ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            } else {
                System.err.println("dialog not found!"); //This line is hit always
            }               
        }


        public static class ProgressDialogFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment {     

            static ProgressDialogFragment newInstance(final String msg) {
                ProgressDialogFragment adf = new ProgressDialogFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                bundle.putString("alert-message", msg);

                adf.setArguments(bundle);
                return adf;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                this.setCancelable(false);
                int style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, theme = 0;
                setStyle(style,theme);
            }

            @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

                String message = bundle.getString("alert-message");


                ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                if(message != null){
                    dialog.setMessage(message);
                }

                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setIndeterminate(true);

                return dialog;
            }       
        }

    }
```

After rotating the device, the AsyncTask is cancelled. I'm calling `closeDielog` from `onPostExecute` and also from `onCancelled`. The dialog never gets closed because the tag ID is not found (`findFragmentByTag` returns null). I'm puzzled with this. The tag is a static String in my implementation activity so there's no chance of it being lost or changed between the calls to `showProgressDialog` and `closeDialog`.

Any idea/hint/suggestion will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: probably your fragmentmanager should be fetched after the rotation is done

Comment: @njzk2 I'm fetching it every time I call `showProgressDialog` and `closeDialog`. I'm not holding a reference to it anywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that I'm cancelling the `AsyncTask` in the activity's `onDestroy`. This is ok to get rid of the bg thread, but `AsyncTask.onCancelled` is no place to close a fragment, because it runs AFTER the activity has been destroyed. Before that, a new activity is created, and the fragment manager restores a new dialog (even if it was created with `setRetainInstance(false)`, which I guess is the default).

The timeline of calls is something like this:

1. screen rotation triggers a config change
2. old activity enters `onDestroy`, cancels the asynctask.
3. old dialog enters `onDetach`.
4. new activity is created.
5. new dialog is created, gets attached to new activity and is shown.
6. the old task `onCancel` executes, calls `closeDialog`, but the tag is not found.

My error was assuming the string tag identified a fragment globally in the application context, but it turns out that the actual fragment ID assigned by the fragment manager is a combination of fragment tag/id and its activity id. When the activity is destroyed, their fragments are detached, and after this point, even if a new fragment with the same tag/id is in the foreground, as it is attached to a different activity, the fragment manager returns null when the old activity calls findFragmentByTag.

However this tag/id is enough for the new fragment to be passed the arguments bundle of the old fragment. This duality is confusing, but it also enables a hack: We can populate the arguments bundle of the fragment in its `onStop` callback with a "cancelled" flag, an query about it in the `onResume` callback, where it calls dismiss itself if the flag is found. That way I can have a progress dialog that conceptually belongs to the AsyncTask, and dies with it.