# how to resume multiple fragments in the last state

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm a beginner in Android and I need help please :(

I have 3 fragments in the main activity and each of the fragments has 4 buttons. What i want to achieve is to keep the fragment's last state persistent while moving from any of  fragment to another, with the help of backstack. How do I do it ? Thank you

```
public class FragmentTraining extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

    Button fragOneBtn;
    Button fragTwoBtn;
    Button fragThreeBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_stack);
        initialize();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.new_fragment1:
            addFragmentToStack("id_one");
            break;
        case R.id.new_fragment2:
            addFragmentToStack("id_two");
            break;
        case R.id.new_fragment3:
            addFragmentToStack("id_three");
            break;
        }
    }

    private void initialize() {
        fragOneBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_fragment1);
        fragTwoBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_fragment2);
        fragThreeBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_fragment3);

        fragOneBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        fragTwoBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        fragThreeBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    void addFragmentToStack(String tag) {
        Fragment newFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
        Log.d("debug", "newFragment: " + newFragment + " , tag: " + tag);
        if (newFragment == null) {
            newFragment = new FragmentInstances();
        }
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fl_container, newFragment, tag);
        ft.commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: I have tried findFragmentByTag(tag) but it's not working. -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to code to its life cycle through its parent activity.

You will have the `onPause, onResume, onStop, and onStart` methods to work with.

There is quite a bit of logic behind this so here is a [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle) to help you, sorry for no code snippet :P

Comment: Come brother :D i need you to please help me on findFragmentByTag(tag) statement. why won't this work -_- my code is running but newFragment receives a null :(

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677244/fragmentmanager-findfragmentbytag-returns-null @user3722382